# how do you solve $(x^2-5x+5)^{x^2-36} =1$

Tags: quadratics

Can someone please show me how they would work it out as I have never come across this before.

$$(x^2-5x+5)^{x^2-36} =1$$

Comment: I think this question has been asked before quite recently. Either the base term is 1 or the exponent is zero

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1396086/finding-the-value-of-x-from-a-complex-form-of-absolute-value and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1398012/how-do-you-solve-x2-5x5x2-36-1?lq=1

Answer (score 8):

It's kind of a trick question; there's no *general* way to solve that kind of equations (save for numerically), if the right-hand side had been anything else than $1$.

However, you should know that $a^b=1$ only if $a=1$ or $b=0$ (or $a=-1$ and $b$ even), so you can break it into three ordinary quadratic equations that you can solve separately.

Comment: What about $x=2$?

Comment: @Servaes: Good point. So the case $a=-1$ needs to be handled and checked carefully too.

Comment: What about $a=\mathrm e$ and $b=2\pi\mathrm i$?

Comment: @celtschk: I'm assuming $x$ is to be real; otherwise it would have been a $z$. :-) Otherwise we get a whole slew of solutions to $(x^2+36)(2\pi i k+\operatorname{Log}(x^2-5x+5)) = 2\pi i m$, which wouldn't look pretty at all, and most of the solutions would only be solution if you pick the right branch of the multivalued exponentiation function.

Answer (score 0):

We have that $a^b=1$ if and only if $a=1$ and arbitrary $b$ or $b=0$ and arbitrary $a$ (one might have to talk about the case $a=b=0$). Having this you should be able to get two seperate equations from $$(x^2-5x+5)^{x^2-36}=1$$ which can be easily solvedfor $x$.

Edit: I should drink a cup of coffee first after getting up...one also has to consider $a=-1$ and $b=2k$ for $k\in\mathbb N$, e.g. $(-1)^2=(-1)^4=(-1)^6=\dots =1$.